# 8086 Assembly Language Program to print from A to Z

Tags: assembly, stack, dos, x86-16, cpu-registers

I have the following program that would print from A to Z with a space in between them. In the following program I understood the rest of the code but didn't understand why the `PUSH DX` and `POP DX` instructions are used. If I run the code without using `PUSH DX` and `POP DX`, it would just print "!" instead of the characters.

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    VAL DB 'A'

.code
    MAIN PROC
        SPACE MACRO
            MOV DL, ' '
            MOV AH, 02h;
            INT 21H    
        ENDM
        
        MOV AX, @DATA
        MOV DS, AX
        
        MOV CL, 26
        MOV DL, 65 ; MOV DL, VAL
        
        PRINT:
            MOV AH, 02H
            INT 21H
            PUSH DX
            SPACE
            POP DX
            INC DL
            DEC CL
            JNZ PRINT
            
        MOV AH, 4CH
        INT 21H        
            
    MAIN ENDP
    END MAIN
```

Comment: Related: a Codegolf.SE answer: [Print the ASCII Code page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249314) and [another answer on the same question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249247/print-the-ascii-code-page/249392#249392)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DX` register starts out loaded with 65, the ASCII code for `A`, the `DH` and `DL` registers are the upper and lower half, respectively of `DX`.

The `SPACE` macro loads a 32 (the ASCII code for space) into DL, overwriting whatever is there. The `PUSH DX` `POP DX` saves and restores the state of the register while the space in-between characters is printed. As to why you see `!`, that is because without restoring DX after the space has been printed, you will simply increment 32 to 33 and print that character.

Answer (score 3):

In SPACE You set DL to space character, but in main loop You use DL as the A to Z chars. Expansion of SPACE overwrites DL, so You store it to the stack before it and retreive it back after the SPACE.

Answer (score 0):

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA

MAIN PROC 

    MOV BL,65
    MOV CL,26


PRINT:

    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,BL
    INC BL
    DEC CL
    INT 21H


    MOV DL,0DH
    INT 21H
    MOV DL,0AH
    INT 21H

 JNZ PRINT

  MOV AH,4CH
  INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: it's a simple way to print capital letter A to Z

Answer (score 0):

```
org 100h

.model small
.data 
     msg1 db 13,10, " Print A to Z characters: $"
     
.code 
main proc
    
    mov ax,@data
    mov dx,ax
    
    mov dx,offset msg1
    
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    
 mov cx,25
mov dx,65
mov ah,2
int 21h
labelname:

 
   inc dx
mov ah,2
int 21h  

loop labelname  
               
  mov ah,4ch
int 21h             


main endp
end main
```

Comment: This has the same (non)segment-register bug as your answer on [How to convert the uppercase to lowercase character in assembly language 8086](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833971) - a DOS `.com` program (`org 100h`) shouldn't use `@data` at all, leave `DS` unmodified.  This happens to work because you write it to DX, not DS, which does nothing: you might as well have done `mov ax, 1` / `mov dx, 2` for all the effect it has on your program.  It's a confusing distraction for beginners, code that shouldn't be there but looks almost like a standard idiom for `.exe` programs.